# CSS child selector higher precedence than class selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, operator-precedence

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="form-square">
     <div class="seven-col">
        Hello World!
      </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
div.form-square > div {
    padding: 50px;
}

.seven-col {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Firefox and Firebug is using the first of the two CSS rules. How come "div.form-square > div" has higher precedence than ".seven-col" which is more specific?

Comment: context (being "inside") is not "more specific" as they are both a div.

Comment: For me, <div class="seven-col"> is more specific because it's specified in the HTML "a lá inline-style". It says clearly "use seven-col" class on me.

Comment: You could then use `div.form-square.seven-col` to make it specify just that second one with that structure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`div.form-square > div` consists of 1 class selector + 2 type selectors (plus a child combinator).

`.seven-col` consists of 1 class selector.

The number of class selectors is equal, so the comparison is done in type selectors. The first selector has more type selectors so it is more specific.

Specificity is based on the number of each kind of selector *in the entire thing*, not for the part on the right hand side of the rightmost combinator.

(NB:  The first example also has what CSS 2 calls a child selector, but that doesn't count towards specificity and describes a relationship between elements rather than a feature of an element, which probably why CSS 3 is renaming it to the child combinator).

Comment: In other words, this has nothing to do with `>`. Combinators are never counted in specificity.

Comment: Thus, "more specific" given more selectors +1, being "inside" has nothing to do with specificity as context means nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the first rule is more specific than the second, because a class only selector has a fairly low priority.

Answer (score 0):

`.seven-col` has 1 class = +1

`div.form-square > div` has 2 elements and 1 class = +3

Check it out with this CSS specificity calculator:
http://www.suzyit.com/tools/specificity.php